# Identify pattern in words

Tags: excel, vba, design-patterns, match

I have a question I believe is quite simple, but I don't know the proper way to do it.

Basically, I would like my program to be able to identify words with a certain pattern in it, and if so, to extract what's before the pattern.

The pattern would be, in this case `/F`, specifically at the end of the word, and it would extract what's before.

For example, if the program finds `21/F`, it will identify it as a good match and will extract `21`. But if the word was `21/Fudge`, it wouldn't do anything.

Do you know the way to look for a match at a specific position in the word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do:

```
If str Like "*/F" Then
    before=Left(str, Len(str)-len("/F"))
Else
    'No match!
End If
```

Comment: No, `"21/Fudge" Like "*/F" = False`. You will have to branch.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a regular expression, something like this:

```
\b\w+?(\d+)\/F\b
```

This will help you match any digits before "/F" and ignore the rest of the word. In order to use it in VBA you will need to add a reference to 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5' and here's the VBA behind this. Pattern is "\b\w+?(\d+)/F\b"

```
Public Sub Extract(Pattern as String, Text as String)

   Dim regEx As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
   Dim matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection

   Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")   ' Create a regular expression.

   regEx.Pattern = Pattern
   Set matches = regEx.Execute(Text)

   Dim i as Long

   For i = 0 To (matches.Count - 1)
       Debug.Print Matches.Item(i)
   Next i

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.